# How to get the root with simplexml xpath function

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get the root node of a simpleXml element, but it doesn't find anything. This is my code example:

```
$xml = <<<XML
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/LSP%20iShip/LSP%20Dossiers/Standard%20iShip%20Mappings/iShip%20XSD's/iOrder.xsd">
    <Reference>21EW400084SA</Reference>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Street1>Ally 3</Street1>
    <Zipcode>0</Zipcode>
    <City>ESPANA</City>
    <CountryCode>ES</CountryCode>
</Order>
XML;

$simpleXML = simplexml_load_string($xml);

var_dump($simpleXML->xpath('/'));
```

var_dump results in the output:

```
array(0) {}
```

The xpath query in our main program is a variable input. It could be the root, or the path to a child. When the variable input is '/', it returns nothing (as you can see in the above example). How can I make it return the root node?

Answer (score 1):

The xpath query `/` will not return anything, because it's an empty search. The leading `/` says the query starts at the root, but it still needs something to search. I suspect you want to try `$simpleXML->xpath('/Order')` or `$simpleXML->xpath('/*')`.

Comment: In this specific instance I believe Marco wanted the xpath expression `/Order` which would return the root element.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming `Object` in my answer was a typo for `Order`. Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

The proper XPath expression is `/*`.

```
var_dump($simpleXML->xpath('/*'));
```

or, for the `SimpleXMLElement` object:

```
var_dump($simpleXML->xpath('/*')[0]);
```